# How to verify User Input against single and multiple occurrence of Regular Expression in shell

Tags: regex, bash, sh

In my shell script i want to validate user input against regular expression, Following code is fine for one entry

```
read -p "Please enter Box Number : " BN
BN=${BN^^}
while ! [[ "${BN}" =~ ^(XDXX[0-9]{3}050-0)$ ]]; do
    read -p "Please enter Box Number : " BN
done
```

But now i want to allow user to input multiple entries like

```
xdxx001050-0, xdxx831050-0
xdxx001050-0, xdxx831050-0, xdxx121050-0
xdxx456050-0, xdxx789050-0, xdxx222050-0, xdxx567050-0
```

**Update1:**
 invalid input as same value repeating

```
xdxx001050-0, xdxx001050-0
```

How i can extend my regular expression to validate one or multiple inputs in one line

Comment: Does `^(XDXX[0-9]{3}050-0)(,\s*XDXX[0-9]{3}050-0)*$` work for you? You could also split on the comma (then trim whitespace or just split on `\s*,\s*`) and reuse your original regex (cleaner and easier)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the only requirement is to validate the input than you can use the '(RE)+' to accept one or more expressions:

```
RE='(XDXX[0-9]{3}050-0)'
# Multiple items, separated with ', ', on a single line.
MULTI_RE="^($RE, )*$RE$"

# Loop until valid input arrives
until [[ "$BN" =~ $MULTI_RE ]] ; do
    read -p "Enter:" BN
    BN=${BN^^}
done
# Process $BN here
```

Minor fix to original question: code applies the uppercase (${BN^^}) on every input line.

Comment: this works fine but while testing i realize we should also have check so input should not be repeated.

Comment: @ImranRazaKhan - can you clarify - provide sample input that is valid, and sample input that should be rejected ? On surface, there is no easy way to check for non-repeated data with regular expressions.REGEXP only test